# What am I missing in my FPGA math operations?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vivado

I am trying to design a module in VHDL to convert one range to another range.  For example, I want to convert a range of 10 - 100 to a range of 0 - 15.  When I put all the math on one line of code, it works as expected in both simulations and on my Basys3 dev board.  However, in Vivado 2020.1 I am getting timing errors.  In order to fix the timing errors, I broke the equation up into separate registers.  I believe this is called pipelining.  After breaking the equation up into separate registers, it works in a behavior simulation, but will not work when I upload it to my dev board.  Any ideas why it won't work on my board?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Range_Converter is
    generic (
        g_Old_Max : integer := 100;
        g_Old_Min : integer := 10;
        g_New_Max : integer := 15;
        g_New_Min : integer := 0
    );
    port (
        i_Clk       : in std_logic;
        i_Old_Value : in integer range g_Old_Min to g_Old_Max;
        o_New_Value : out integer range g_New_Min to g_New_Max
    );
end Range_Converter;

architecture RTL of Range_Converter is

    constant c_Old_Range : integer := (g_Old_Max - g_Old_Min);
    constant c_New_Range : integer := (g_New_Max - g_New_Min);

    signal reg1 : integer range g_New_Min to g_New_Max := 0;
    signal reg2 : integer range g_New_Min to g_New_Max := 0;
    signal reg3 : integer range g_New_Min to g_New_Max := 0;
    signal reg4 : integer range g_New_Min to g_New_Max := 0;

begin

    process (i_Clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(i_Clk) then

            --This works but there are timing errors.
            -- o_New_Value <= ((((i_Old_Value - g_Old_Min) * c_New_Range) / c_Old_Range) + g_New_Min);

            --No timing errors, but will not work.
            reg1        <= (i_Old_Value - g_Old_Min);
            reg2        <= (reg1 * c_New_Range);
            reg3        <= (reg2 / c_Old_Range);
            reg4        <= (reg3 + g_New_Min);
            o_New_Value <= reg4;

        end if;
    end process;

end RTL;
```

Comment: Did you check the RTL and implemented diagrams. Does the circuit look what you had expected??

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, Tricky.  I found the problem.  The size the reg2 register needed to be larger.

Comment: Simulation should have caught that! Not enough testcases?